# I'm using django framework. i'm stuck up with how to show image on my home page

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django framework .I just want to show simple image on my home page (localhost:8000). I'm getting confused how to use models.py, views.py and urls.py. Can you help me to show just simple image file.
Thank you.

Comment: Or try to narrow down your confusion and ask to clarify it?

Comment: RTFM right here https://www.djangoproject.com/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display static image, django docs for [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/) and  [django.contrib.staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) may help.

You can

- edit your project's settings.py and add appropriate static files settings

  ```
  # Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
  # Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
  # in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
  # Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
  STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/static/root/directory'

  # URL prefix for static files.
  STATIC_URL = '/your_static_url_prefix/'

  STATICFILES_DIRS = (
      '/path/to/your/static/directory',
  )
  ```
- put your image somewhere under you STATICFILES directory, example at

  ```
  '/path/to/your/static/directory/images/theimage.png'
  ```
- Display the image from your home page template, example by

  ```
  <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/theimage.png"/>
  ```

You can also read tutorials from the official django documentation to know the basics on how models,views,urls and templates work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read something about it. There are some good tutorials in the net. First of all check [django book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/), you can also watch this [video tutorial](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=1100000&fromSeriesID=110)